# Checkout page loading unauthenticated scripts

Tags: checkout, security, https

I am getting a little shield warning me that my checkout page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources.

I am guessing that some file(s) are being loaded via http instead of https, os some other similar error?

How do I find out which script(s) are being incorrectly loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers have a console that opens with <kbd>F12</kbd>. There you should see detailed error messages like this:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://example.com/media/image.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Most likely this comes from an extension/theme that either does not use `Mage::getBaseUrl()` properly or includes external scripts over HTTP (like for tracking)

If such external scripts are also available via HTTPS, you should search for them in the code (XML or PHTML files) and change the URLs either to `https://example.com/...` (to always use HTTPS) or to `//example.com/...` (to use the same protocol as the current page)

Comment: Thanks, I had to use ctrl alt J to access the console, but this enabled me to identify the problem.  Now I'm after the solution though!