# Checkout page is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, login, forms

I customized Magento 1.9.2 **rwd** theme with CSS. All pages working fine except onepage checkout accordion. When i click checkout button the form is not showing.
[image]

The login form is not showing there. I am new to magento can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Check browser console any error there?

Comment: when i check browser console it shows some errors which i listed below        Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
onepage:718 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setAttribute is not a function
opcheckout.js:295 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function
onepage:909 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setAttribute is not a function
opcheckout.js:433 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function
opcheckout.js:596 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function
opcheckout_rwd.js:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: Checkout is not defined

Comment: From your comment it's due to jQuery conflict. Have you added any jQuery or changed any existing jQuery ?

Comment: yes, I have added jquery.js to my theme. Should i remove that? how to avoid jquery conflict?? Is it possible??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkout page loading unauthenticated scripts](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74098/checkout-page-loading-unauthenticated-scripts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is more than one jquery library. then remove it. Use only one library in page.

In your `local.xml`:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs" name="jquery" as="jquery">
        <script>jquery.js</script>
    </action>
    <action method="addJs">
        <script>noconflict.js</script>
    </action>
</reference>
```

and `noconflict.js` would simply be

```
$.noConflict();
```

Fore more information take a look at here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175941/magento-jquery-conflict

Hope this make sense to you

Comment: I have made changes. But still its not working.

Comment: What error coming now?

Comment: prototype.js:5653 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function observe @ prototype.js:5653(anonymous function) @ (index):1121
prototype.js:5653 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a functionobserve @ prototype.js:5653(anonymous function) @ accordion.js:35(anonymous function) @ prototype.js:391(anonymous function) @ prototype.js:825each @ prototype.js:824Accordion.initialize @ accordion.js:34klass @ prototype.js:101(anonymous function) @ (index):1147
prototype.js:5734 Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a functionfire

Comment: Check jquery loading after prototype.js

Comment: sorry.. i didn't get you..

Comment: Check page source. jquery must load after prototype.js

Comment: yes.. jquery is  loading after prototype.js                                                                                 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/magento/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/magento/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: After this `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`  add `noconflict.js`. check my answer.

Comment: Yaah.. its in same order as u said. nonconflict.js file is already there in js/lib  folder. Should I add another nonconflict.js to my theme??

Comment: Is there only on js lib in that page? or loading multiple jquery lib?

Comment: two jquery files are there.. i have removed one which is in the theme/js/.. Now its working fine.. Thank you Rohit...

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace prototype.js file from fresh magento backup