# Need help with Checkout.js

Tags: checkout, magento-1

I got these errors.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Checkout is not defined
    at opcheckout.js:26
opcheckout_rwd.js:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: Checkout is not defined
    at opcheckout_rwd.js:26
(index):625 Uncaught ReferenceError: Billing is not defined
    at (index):625
(index):660 Uncaught ReferenceError: Payment is not defined
    at (index):660
(index):701 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentMethod' of undefined
    at (index):701
(index):723 Uncaught ReferenceError: Checkout is not defined
    at (index):723
```

My checkout isn't working.

Comment: PLZ someone help me, Im helpless ;( im a noob in magento and i don't know what i did wrong, My checkout isn''t working anymore

Comment: PLease check you have multiple jquery  in same page?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108291/checkout-page-is-not-working